# Sorted data from some services by date angular6

Tags: angular, sorting, angularfire2

I use angular cli 6, angularfire2 and firebase. I have data which come of some services. I hope you understand my problem.

```
In service1, i have somes Date1 : Date1.value1, Date1.value2, Date1.value3* ;
In service2, i have somes Date2 ; Date2.value1, Date2.value2,
In service3, i have somes Date3 ; Date3.value1,
...
```

I want to display my data in the template chronologically, sorted by all my dates. 
All my date have the same Pipe format, and all Dates are stocked as string in firebase.
Soo, i think that i must sort all of my dates.value by a unique filter ?

Comment: So, are you asking how to sort in JavaScript / TypeScript? Here's the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: ok, so i must filter in front not in firebase ? thanks

Comment: You must do whatever you want to do. If you want firebase to sort, then ask firebase to sort (I don't know much about firebase, but I guess it's possible). If you want the frontend to sort, then make the frontend sort.

Comment: lol ok so i will go to sort in frontend ! thank you for your help